# Graphical pattern - 5x5 grids with "x"s

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

A friend of mine made this puzzle. You should find the pattern that explains the movements of the 'x' and find the next item in the sequence. You should draw it in the white box on the right.

[image]

Hint: You should analyze the items in a clockwise motion, so the first item is the one with one 'x', the second is the one with three 'x's, etc.

Comment: Hi adamantino. This exact puzzle was [already posted a few days ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105611/graphical-puzzle-sequence) by another user - was that you with a different account? It seems rather a coincidence otherwise that two people received this exact same puzzle 'from a friend' and brought it to PSE for assistance! :)

Comment: Please refrain from calling out people outright on PSE's comment section, you should flag the puzzle, comment your concerns and let the moderators deal with it.

Comment: @Stiv yea it was me,I just forgot the password of the other account

Comment: @Smartest1here This is not 'calling out people outright' - this is engaging with a fellow user in a perfectly friendly manner. No need for aggression!

Comment: It seemed like you were accusing him of trying to bypass certain PSE rules.

Comment: @adamantino Okay, great - I suspected as much as I wondered why you hadn't just edited the previous post with the extra information. This one looks a lot neater and explains the task much more clearly, so hopefully you'll get an answer this time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> [image]

Explanation

> In each step the "x" has moved 1 step in three directions; left, diagonally, down. And every other step disappear/reappear at the top right corner (original position).
>  [image] So I believe this is the "missing grid" to complete the sequence.

Comment: He says find the next term in the sequence how does your answer answer this.

Comment: @Prim3numbah I think this is really clever - if this is correct, the missing term of the sequence isn't the traditional 'next one' but one of the intermediate steps which is totally missing. That's sneaky, and a nice spot :) +1 from me.

Comment: @Stiv Thanks, yeah, we'll just have to wait and see if this is the intended one :)

Comment: Given that the patterns have to be read in a clockwise fashion, and the empty spot is on the right, this looks totally legitimate to me that empty spot is actually in the middle of the sequence.

Answer (score -2):

I've noticed this pattern, but I think my reasoning is wrong.

The first x in the top right contains all the other x, then in the next big square, the x move 1 little square away. The x move again 1 square away but this time all the x's are 2 little squares away from the top right corner so the light blue x gets added; in the next big square the x move 2 blocks away and a yellow x gets added, in the last big square the x move 2 blocks again a pass through the "wall", like Pac-Man effect but this time the x in the top corner doesn't get added.

[image]